# Fan led light unusual situation

Tags: ceiling-fan, led

We got new fan (hunter)
It came with 4 traditional 40W lights.

I want to replace these with 4 led daylight lights 6 w equivalent to 40W, I think.

When I replace 1,2,3 out of 4 lights they are well lit. 
But the moment I take fourth traditional light off the socket are all dim. With all 4 led also it is dim.

As long I leave at least one old light everything is pretty brights. Any solution?

Comment: A bit surprised that you found a **new** fan that uses traditional 40W bulbs. Model # of the fan?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Does this fan have a dimmer for its lights? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: "traditional" is not enough information.   Are they incandescent, compact fluorescent, halogen, ??

Comment: No dimmer. Fan came with 4 incandescent lights with smaller about  10 mm  nozzle that goes in socket. . I am trying to replace them with 4 led bulbs. I have done 3. If I change fourth all bulbs get  extremely dimmed.